River swim distance in a Triathlon.
A 440m  swim upstream in Paris.
1.3 and 1.4 meters per second competitors.
River flow .7 mps
Start at the downstream buoy marker swimming up on the 440 leg
1.3 mps minus .7 flow speed is .6 mps
440 up at .6 mps is 733.3 secs to the top buoy.
During this time, the competitors “swim speed through the water” is 1.3 meters per second.
733.3 x 1.3 is 953.3 m swim “through the water distance”
The 1.4 mps swimmer starts that same leg.
1.4 swimmer minus .7
440 up at .7 mps is 628.5 seconds.
628.5 x 1.4 is 880 meters is the “through the water distance.”
Downstream
1.3  plus .7
440 down at 2mps is 220 seconds
1.3 mps x 220 is 286 mtr through the water swim distance.
1.4 mtr swimmer.
1.4 plus .7 is 2.1mps
440 down at 2.1 is 209.5 secs
209.5 x 1.4 is
293.3mtr “through the water swim distance.
Notes
Downstream, the slower swimmer swims less distance through the water because of river flow!!
A downstream swimmer could complete that leg just treading water without any through the water speed.
An upstream .7 mps swimmer would never complete that leg even with through the water progress.
If all the legs
swim speed distances are calculated it would indicate an unfair contest.
Also consider the 50 meter cross stream swims where the 1.3 mps swimmer must swim more distance.
So my question here is, was the course design fair or not.
Perhaps my maths went wrong?

Is this a problem in a text somewhere, or are these the results of an experiment you conducted on your own (with a pair of swimmers)?

Please include a diagram/picture of this.

For the swimmer travelling at $1.4\ \mathrm{m/s}$, each second he will travel $1.4-0.7=0.7\ \mathrm{m}$ upstream. It thus takes him $440/0.7=628.571429\ \mathrm{s}$ to complete the leg.
In that time the untethered buoy will travel downstream at a rate of $0.7\ \mathrm{m/s}$, and you can find that over $628.571429\ \mathrm{s}$, it has moved $0.7*628.571429=440\ \mathrm{m}$.
You can use the same process to find the distance the buoy has travelled downstream for the second swimmer. does this answer your question?

Try a different speed swimmer. Is it still 440.

Take a look at— “river swim distance between two fixed posts” is my maths correct there.
